# Want to compare two hashmaps and remove them

Tags: java

I have two hashmaps intialised as below

FieldType is a JAXB object.

```
Map<String, FieldType> onsDetailsMap    =   new LinkedHashMap<String, FieldType>();
Map<String, FieldType> uxDetailsMap =   new LinkedHashMap<String, FieldType>();
```

I'm trying to compare the 'Key' of two hashmap. If two keys are equal I need to fetch the 'Key' and it's JAXB object, write to another hashmap and remove it from the actual hashmap.

Tried to remove it with hashmap.remove(key) but it is throwing a java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

```
for (String key : onsDetailsMap.keySet()) {
if (uxDetailsMap.containsKey(key)) {

    System.out.println("BOTH :: " +key);
    onsDetailsMap.remove(key);

}else {

       System.out.println("ONS only :: " +key);
}
```

Comment: You will have to use iterator, or convert it to arraylist then do stuff.

Answer (score 4):

You cannot iterate over map in for loop and delete entries from this map simultaneously.
Try this

```
Iterator entries = onsDetailsMap.entrySet().iterator();
while (entries.hasNext()) {
  Entry<String, FieldType> entry = (Entry) entries.next();
  if (uxDetailsMap.containsKey(entry.getKey()) {
      System.out.println("BOTH :: " + entry.getKey());
      entries.remove();
  }
}
```

Comment: THe code throws an error, THe method 'contains(Object)' is undefined for Map(String, FieldType). FieldType is a JAXB object.

Comment: Oh, my bad. It should be raw Entry and wrong contains method. I updated answer.

Comment: How do i get the 'Value' of respecive 'Key' ? FieldType is a JAXB object ?

Comment: The if statement in the snippet above is missing a ).

Answer (score 1):

```
 Iterator<String, FieldType> iter = onsDetailsMap.entrySet().iterator();
 while (iter.hasNext()) {
       Entry<String, FieldType> entry = (Entry) entries.next();
       if (uxDetailsMap.contains(entry.getKey()) {          
           iter.remove();
       }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code it is run fine

```
Iterator entries = onsDetailsMap.entrySet().iterator();
            while (entries.hasNext()) {
              Entry entry = (Entry) entries.next();
              if(!uxDetailsMap.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
              {
                  System.out.println("Single value:: " + entry.getKey());
                  entries.remove();
              }
            }
```

Comment: Thank You for the solution. It works. Can i also get the code on how do i get the value of that particulat key ? Map<String, JAXBObject>.

Comment: Which value you want from map unique or duplicate one? and in which map you want to save exit map or new one?

Comment: Want the value of the respective 'key', here 'value' is a JAXB object.

Comment: how do i typecast object to List ?

Comment: My actual purpose is to create a xml from the object. So need to get the object (value of key) in hashmap.

Comment: map will return value again key than how do you create your or generate xml file it's depend on you if possibal than post code so may be i will help u.....

Answer (score 0):

```
for (Iterator<Map.Entry<String, Integer>> iterator = onsDetailsMap.entrySet().iterator(); iterator.hasNext();) {
        Map.Entry<String, Integer> entry = iterator.next();
        if (uxDetailsMap.containsKey(entry.getKey()))
                iterator.remove();

}
```